# Find the new email of MessagesArrived event MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

How does I get the new email(s) that triggered a MessagesArrived event using MailKit??

After what I see, I'm getting a sender as IMailFolder and e as MessagesArrivedEventArgs.
The only thing I see in e is e.Count which telling me how many news mails that has arrived I assume. What I want is the email in MimeMessage form that has arrived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will need to do is store the e.Count value. Once the current command is done (client.Idle()? folder.Fetch()? etc), you will then want to either:

1. call `folder.Fetch (folder.Count - count, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId)` to get the most recent messages added to the folder.
2. or call `folder.Search (SearchQuery.Recent)` which will give only *new* messages that you have not viewed before.

Once you get the UID(s), you can then call `folder.GetMessage (uid);` to get the message(s) as MimeMessage(s).

Note: technically, the MessagesArrived event is emitted whenever the IMAP server sends the client an EXISTS event where the number of messages in the folder has *increased*. Since the e.Count value is calculated as `NewMessageCount - OldMessageCount`, it might actually be misleading since you could have a situation such as:

1. Open a folder, current message count is 10
2. Move a message out of the folder
3. while the message is being moved, you get 2 new messages
4. MessagesArrived event is emitted with a Count of 1 (10 - 1 + 2 = 11... 11 - 10 = 1)

It might actually be best to listen to the ImapFolder.CountChanged event instead and do your own book keeping.

Comment: A thing to keep in mind (that I struggled a lot with during this issue) is, that Inbox.Count may contain mails flagged DELETED, and might give you the wrong count, if you seamlessly use INBOX.Count() as your count changed tracker.